# Show my custom points in route in maps without paid version

Tags: javascript, java, php, google-maps, bing-maps

Suppose I have a route from Place A to B and 1,2,3 are respectively my cycle stoppage. I want people to the only search for route and he will able to see the available stoppage between the searched route.

Search Query will :
**Source: A,**
**Destination: B**

Output:
*[in map View]*
Show the route of **A to B** and the stoppage points **1,2,3**
where 1,2,3 has its own *latitude and longitude*

Comment: Are you using Google Maps?

Comment: I am not using anyone (google/bing/else), I will go for the working method whether it will may google or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I had used google map for such functionality and the snippet is as below

```
PolylineOptions mPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
.......
ArrayList<LatLong> latLngs = ....// list of route polypoints to draw path

mPolylineOptions.addAll(latLngs).width(10).color(polylineColor);

mMap.addPolyline(mPolylineOptions);

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(stopPoint1).flat(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_car)));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(stopPoint2).flat(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_car)));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(stopPoint3).flat(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_car)));
```

Comment: will it add the marker to the specific latitude and longitude

Comment: last three-lines are to add marker where stopPoint1,2 and 3 are latlong value itself

Comment: Here is the link for your ref, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This is also easy to do with the [Bing Maps SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/sdk-native/):

> ```java
> // Create layer to add your collection of map elements
> MapElementLayer mapLayer = new MapElementLayer();
>
> // Create geo path with the route points
> ArrayList<Geoposition> positions = new ArrayList<Geoposition>();
> positions.add(new Geoposition(routePoint1.getLatitude(), routePoint1.getLongitude()));
> positions.add(new Geoposition(routePoint2.getLatitude(), routePoint2.getLongitude()));
> ...
> positions.add(new Geoposition(routePointN.getLatitude(), routePointN.getLongitude()));
>
> // Create and add route polyline to the map layer.
> MapPolyline route = new MapPolyline();
> route.setPath(new Geopath(positions));
> mapLayer.getElements().add(route);
>
> // Create and add stop icons to the map layer.
> MapIcon stop1 = new MapIcon();
> stop1.setLocation(new Geopoint(stopPoint1.getLatitude(), routePoint1.getLongitude()));
> mapLayer.getElements().add(stop1);
> ...
>
> // Add layer to display map elements in the map control
> mapView.getLayers().add(mapLayer);
> ```

If you need a [web control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/) instead, note that there are also samples in the Interactive SDK for [polyline](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/adddefaultpolyline), [pushpin](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/adddefaultpushpin) and adding multiple items to a [layer](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/addmultiplelayeritems).